# SmsLib App working in Eclipse but exported runnable Jar has the following issue?

Tags: java, eclipse, message-queue, executable-jar, smslib

The following issue. Could you please anyone help on this issue?

In Eclipse same application that is desktop based application working fine. but once after export as executable Jar File the following issue is comming. it is log file.

try to send SMS via dongle as queued MSGs

```
SMSLib: A Java API library for sending and receiving SMS via a GSM modem or other supported gateways.
This software is distributed under the terms of the Apache v2.0 License.
Web Site: http://smslib.org
Version: 3.5.2
JRE Version: 1.7.0_21
JRE Impl Version: 23.21-b01
O/S: Windows 7 / amd64 / 6.1
Queue directory not defined. Queued messages will not be saved to filesystem.
Initialized.
Running...
NotifyQueueManager running...
Initialized.
Running...
DelayQueueManager running...
Initialized.
Running...
GTW: modem.com1: Starting gateway, using Generic AT Handler.
GTW: modem.com1: Opening: COM3 @921600
GTW: modem.com1: Closing: COM3 @921600
NotifyQueueManager end...
DelayQueueManager end...
Running...
NotifyQueueManager running...
Stopped.
GTW: modem.com1: Stopping gateway...
NotifyQueueManager end...
GTW: modem.com1: Closing: COM3 @921600
GTW: modem.com1: Gateway stopped.
Running...
NotifyQueueManager running...
NotifyQueueManager end...
Running...
NotifyQueueManager running...
Stopped.
```

Comment: What part of this shows the error you're experiencing? What is the expected result?  There do not appear to be any Runtime Exceptions or obvious error messages, so I'm not sure how to help.

Comment: Application is build as Java project from Eclipse. There  i have used SMSLib to send SMS for multiple users via dongle (COM port -Modem). When launching from Eclipse - that means Run or Debug button it will send SMSs correctly. it is Swing based GUI application using another threading to SMSs in background.

Comment: Application is build as Java project from Eclipse. There  i have used SMSLib to send SMS for multiple users via dongle (COM port -Modem). When launching from Eclipse - that means Run or Debug button it will send SMSs correctly. it is Swing based GUI application using another threading to SMSs in background. But after exporting executable Jar files it is not working. if SMSs sent sccessfully then this test file from Logger class will only have phone number and numbers and time stamp details. but here it has this Queue Directory not defined MSS. Same time SMS did not send to.

Comment: It may help to show some of the code you're using.  And perhaps output logs from when it works in Eclipse.  The more you can give to help us understand the problem, the more likely it is that someone can help solve it. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have this case try my solution (I had the same problem and it solved my problem this: **in fact it is noted in the documentation SMSlib**)

[image]